# ifelse with data.table

Tags: r, date, if-statement, data.table

Here is my data:

```
BuyDate       SellDate     Number
2015-01-01    NA           1
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   1
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   -1
2016-12-09    NA           -1
```

I want to create a new column `Start`, so I can have the following result.

```
BuyDate       SellDate     Number    Start
2015-01-01    NA           1         2015-01-01
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   1         2015-01-01
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   -1        2015-01-03
2016-12-09    NA           -1        2016-12-09
```

The code is:

```
data[,Start:=ifelse(Number=="1",BuyDate,ifelse(is.na(SellDate),BuyDate,SellDate))]
```

However, I get:

```
BuyDate       SellDate     Number    Start
2015-01-01    NA           1         1420070400
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   1         1420070400
2015-01-01    2015-01-03   -1        1420243200
2016-12-09    NA           -1        1481241600
```

How can I solve this?

```
str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':
 $BuyDate : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-12-09"
 $SellDate: POSIXct, format: NA "2015-01-03" "2015-01-03" NA
 $Number  : chr  "1" "1" "-1" "-1"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is better not to use `ifelse` as the 'Date' can get coerced to `integer` storage values, instead, we assign (`:=`) 'Start' as the 'SellDate', then specify the logical condition in 'i' for identifying the 'NA' elements  in 'Start' or the 1 in 'Number' and assign (`:=`) the elements in 'BuyDate' that correspond to 'i' to 'Start'

```
data[, Start := SellDate][Number==1, Start := BuyDate
          ][is.na(Start), Start := BuyDate][]
```

As @Cath mentioned in the comments, this can be done in two steps

```
data[, Start := SellDate][(Number==1) | is.na(Start), Start := BuyDate][]
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer more, I think it is good but I cannot fully understand it.

Comment: why not just `data[, Start := SellDate][(Number==1) | is.na(Start), Start := BuyDate][]`?

Comment: @Cath Thanks for the comments.  I was a bit busy with calls, so couldn't reply earlier

Comment: @Cath Minor plus might be auto indexing, especially after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068 Then again, after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1453 your way'd also use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Start variable has to be converted to POSIXct:

```
require(dplyr)
data[, Start:= (ifelse(Number=="1",BuyDate,ifelse(is.na(SellDate),BuyDate,SellDate)) %>% 
         as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01"))]
```

**ADDED:**

Following codes run with `dplyr`. I am not sure why `dplyr` won't work with the example above.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dates <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 1:20)
dates2 <- as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 21:40)

tmp <- data.table(date = dates, date2 = dates2)
tmp[runif(20)>.8, date2 := NA]
tmp[, date3 := (ifelse(is.na(date2), date, date2) %>% as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01"))]
```

Comment: Loading a whole package just to avoid doing `as.POSIXct(ifelse(...), origin="1970-01-01")`?...

Comment: This will run if you load magrittr instead, I guess. I find it fits better with data.table.

Comment: @Frank you mean `magrittr` package?

Comment: @PeterChen Yeah. It supports the `%>%` operator and others. So something like `Start := replace(Number==1, Buydate) %>% replace(is.na(SellDate), BuyDate) %>% as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01")` should work.

Comment: Or `Start := SellDate %>% replace(Number==1, Buydate) %>% replace(is.na(SellDate), BuyDate) %>% as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01")`, I think. (Haven't tested it.)